# How do I redirect output to multiple files whose names are based on current time?

Tags: linux, bash, output-redirect

consider the following command:

```
while true; do echo 'Hit CTRL+C';sleep 1;done >> `date +"%H%M.txt"`
```

when I execute this command, it redirects output to a single file with the filename as the starting time of the command. How can I change this such that it saves to a different file every minute with the file name

```
 date +"%H%M.txt"
```

at that given minute?

EDIT:

```
while true; do echo 'Hit CTRL+C';sleep 1;done
```

is just a substitute for a program that runs for a long time and outputs some data every second.i want to save the data that is output every minute into a separate file without having to start my program over again.

Comment: you mean different file name at the interval of every 1 minute ?

Comment: yes, every minute's output should be in a file with the time as the name

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-evaluate the date on each instance of the loop.

```
while true; do echo 'Hit CTRL+C' > "`date +"%H%M"`.txt"; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: are you sure `sleep 1` gives you 1 minute interval ? As per man page it's 1 second

Comment: `sleep 1` is sleeping for one second.  But `date +"%H%M"` is only changing once per minute, so this is giving the expected result.

Comment: Use append redirect operator `>>` instead of single `>` to avoid overwriting previous contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true ; do 
    echo 'Hit CTRL+C'       # just for the screen
    stock=$( date +"%H%M" ) 

    while [[ $( date +"%H%M" ) == $stock ]] ; do 
        echo 'Hit CTRL+C' $stock
        sleep 1
    done > "$stock.txt"     # no need '>>'
done
```

disk access every minute about

Answer (score 0):

The output of your long time running command should redirect to a intermediate place (`fifo`), then use `cat` to pull log to different files from this fifo in every minute.

Here is a simple script wrapper, use `SIGUSR1` to update log file name. Replace `long-running-cmd` with your command.

```
# in seconds
logger_update_duration=60

background_pid=
main_cmd=

function update_file_name() {
    trap "update_file_name" USR1 # re-establish

    file_name=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.log")
    echo "update file name $file_name"

    cat < ./logger > $file_name &
    # after establish the new, check should kill the old
    if [ x$background_pid != x ];then
        echo "will kill the old $background_pid current is $$"
        kill -TERM $background_pid
    fi
    background_pid=$!
}
trap "update_file_name" USR1

function clean() {
    echo "perform clean..."
    kill -TERM $!
    kill -TERM $main_cmd
    rm logger
}
trap "clean" EXIT


# create logger fifo
[ ! -p logger ] && mkfifo logger

# replace with your long time running operation
./long-running-cmd > ./logger &
main_cmd=$!

while true
do 
    kill -USR1 $$
    sleep ${logger_update_duration}
done
```

The output of `long-running-cmd` should split into different log files in a period of one minute.